# WSO2 AM 1.10.0 validate query parameters

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

To prevent Log injection, I need to validate the query parameters (country, pesticide and crop) in WSO2 AM. the API looks like below,

```
http://172.17.100.149/api/mrldatabase/v1/reports?country=AUS&pesticide=ABew30000&crop=22020347
```

Really appreciate if someone can show me a way of validation.

Comment: you can create a sequence in WSO2 Developer Studio IDE, just open the WSO2 API Manager Perspective, connect to the APIM and in the insequence create a sequence for this validations you want to apply..In your API definition include the sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a custom mediation sequence for this. [See docs](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Adding+Mediation+Extensions).

You can read query params like this. [See this](http://movingaheadblog.blogspot.com/2016/08/wso2-api-manager-how-to-retrieve.html) for more details.

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="admin--Temp:v1.0.0--In">  
      <log level="custom">  
          <property name="SubPath" expression="$ctx:REST_SUB_REQUEST_PATH"/>  
      </log>  
 </sequence>
```

Comment: Thanks heaps for your kind and useful help. I just wonder where I can find the log file which contains property, like say 'SubPath' in your example.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I found the export log. I also used <property name="CountryCode" scope="transport" expression="$url:country" /> to retrieve the query parameters.

Comment: Should I use external XSD file to validate the these parameters, but I do not know how a XSD file can get the parameters from sequence to verify? Or I just verify them in the sequence. Could you please provide me simple examples like countryCode should be three characters long string? thanks.